Reason behind Window function in STFT
Ive been digging the area of stft analysis of discreet time audio signals.
One thing I still can't understand is this - it is common to use window function such as hann, hamminh etc. When doing stft, one reason provides is that it reduces the spectral leakage cause by the signal chunks being finite in time and the artifacts caused by this (delta of a tone in frequency domain becomes a sinc for instance) which does make sense. Another explanation could be the COLA constraint when using some overlapping pracentage (I assume i want to reconstruct the signal), my question is - which one is the main reason? Or is it both regardless of one another ? Or are they somehow connected and represent some deeper meaning?
Thank you.

It’s both.
However, the COLA constraint matters only if the signal has to be reconstructed (analysis/synthesis).
For analysis only, the window used doesn’t need to be COLA.

Thank, I indeed assume reconstruction is needed. So assuming windowing, Is overlapping windows needed for the COLA constraint or for better localization or both as well?

Needed for both!

Just FYI, I put a pretty exhaustive definition for the STFT over here.  Might be useful to point to common component functions.

it is common to use window function such as hann, hamming etc.

It depends on what you're doing with the STFT.  Sometimes one is processing a signal with the STFT.  Then in the signal output, you want your windows to be complementary.  That is the windows of adjacent frames of the STFT, they add to 1 for every sample.
The Hann window is complementary.  So is the Hamming, if scaled a little.

When doing stft, one reason provides is that it reduces the spectral leakage

That's most often the major concern.  The also affects the length of the window.  For analysis only, then complementary windows are not necessary and then usually the big concern is spectral leakage.  This is so your spectrum with frequency components won't get little bumps on the side that can be confused for a separate frequency component.
Sometimes, perhaps, the best analysis window would be something like a Kaiser window.  I dunno if I ever used it with STFT.  I have used the Kaiser window for other purposes, like in designing FIR filters using the window method.
When I was using the STFT for analysis, I liked using the Gaussian window.  (It's an approximation because theoretically the Gaussian never gets to zero, but you cut it off anyway.  Maybe around where the amplitude is $10^{-9}$.)
Anyway, the Fourier Transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian.  No sidelobes.  (Because of the finite truncation, there are tiny sidelobes that are like noise.)  So then, each frequency component has a single Gaussian bump.  And each frequency component can be changing frequency and/or amplitude and that rate of change can be extracted from the Gaussian bump in the frequency domain, in addition to the instantaneous frequency and amplitude and phase of the frequency component.

Sometimes people use the square root of a Hann window, and apply it twice, once during analysis and once during synthesis.  If you are doing time-varying modifications of the signal in the spectral domain, using a window during reconstruction can help reduce artifacts.

Yup.  Another trick is, if you're doing 75% overlap (that is the hop length is $\tfrac14$ of the frame length) is that the Hann$^2$ is complementary and adds to 1.  So you can Hann on the input, FFT, do all of your messing around to the frequency domain data, inverse FFT, and apply another Hann before overlapping and adding.
